# VB.NET DataGridView pick Max NEGATIVE Number under 0

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need to display a **MAX Negative** or least negative number from DataGridView.
But   **Dim max As Decimal = cells.Max** only works for numbers above zero or so it seems.
If I have **values -80.1 , -70.1 and etc.** it displays **MAX as 0** if I have **1.1** in column it will display **1.1 as MAX**

*Is there a **cells property** that can be set to actually evaluate **all #s** instead of **0** and above for **MAX** **VAL**?*

Range can be **positive** or **negative** for example **-100 to 100 = Result 100, -80 to -10 = Result -10.**

From what I seen so far the only way to do this is **evaluate column 1st** and if it contain at least one positive number then call on cells.max

If all numbers are negative then use numbers.Where(Function(d) d < Decimal.Zero).Max() - as someone suggested.

Please suggest if any better methods exist,

Thanks!

Code is below:

```
Public Sub find_high()

        Dim row As String() = New String() {"MAX"}
        dgv_all_results.Rows.Add(row)

        Dim tada As Integer = (dgv_all_results.Columns.Count - 1)

        Dim rt As Integer = dgv_all_results.Rows.Count - 1

        For z = 1 To tada ' ID COLUMS


            Dim cells = From r As DataGridViewRow In dgv_all_results.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
              Where Not r.IsNewRow _
              Select CDec(r.Cells(z).Value) ' val 0 represents colum

            Dim max As Decimal = cells.Max

            Dim maxval As New cell With {.columnIndex = z, .rowIndex = Array.IndexOf(cells.ToArray, max)}
            dgv_all_results.Item(z, rt).Value = (Math.Round(max, 3))

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Could you leverage the ABS() function to give you the absolute value?

Comment: @Hursey  hi I actually do need an exact value since data in the table comes from outside

Answer (score 1):

This has got nothing to do with cells in a grid. You want to get the largest number that satisfies specific criteria from a list so you should start by getting that list of numbers. How you do that isn't relevant to the operation of getting the maximum number. If you want to get the numbers from all the cells in a specific column in the grid:

```vb
Dim numbers = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Select(Function(dgvr) CDec(dgvr.Cells(columnIndex).Value))
```

If you want something different then you do it a different way. Regardless, you need to get a list of the numbers you want to act on.

Now that you have the numbers, it's a simple case of filtering based on your desired criteria and then getting the largest:

```vb
Dim maxNegativeNumber = numbers.Where(Function(d) d < Decimal.Zero).Max()
```

You can do it all in a single line if you want:

```vb
Dim maxNegativeNumber = DataGridView1.Rows.
                                      Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().
                                      Select(Function(dgvr) CDec(dgvr.Cells(columnIndex).Value)).
                                      Where(Function(d) d < Decimal.Zero).
                                      Max()
```

Just note that that code assumes that every cell in the column contains a number. If some may not then you'll need to filter the cells with `Where` before calling `Select`. It also assumes that there is at least one negative number.

Comment: Hi, I have a full list of numbers generated in column. For statement goes thru it and picks up MAX and MIN. I can write a function around this to find MAX number by manually comparing all the values and etc. But I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this. It works for MIN hence than I would expect it to work for MAX in the same way. To add MAX number can be negative or positive but it should be most positive from column, thanks!

Comment: @Alek, *"To add MAX number can be negative or positive"*. That's not what you said in the actual question. How about you ask the que4stion you actually want answered in the question. Don't change the question in a comment on an answer. If you no longer want an answer to the question you asked, delete this question and create a new one. If you want an answer on a different question as well then create a new question for that.

Comment: @Alek, that said, I've shown you how to get a list of numbers from a grid column, filter it and then get largest. If you want the largest from the list without filtering then just don't filter.

Comment: I have update the question with the code as well. I can get the numbers, answer provided assumes all numbers in column are below 0 which is NOT the case. If no one else will have a suggestion that is more efficient than I will use this and create two functions based on values in the column, Thanks!

Comment: *"answer provided assumes all numbers in column are below 0"*. Except it freakin' doesn't! Why would it specifically filter out numbers that weren't below zero if it was assuming that all numbers were below zero? I even state explicitly what the assumptions are and that's not one of them. If there are no negative numbers then you can't get the largest negative number, so don't even try. You can filter first and put the results in an array and then test whether there's anything in that array. If there isn't then there's no max to get. If there is, you know how to get it.

Comment: I suggest you pass on this question. You sound frustrated for no reason. My question is very simple get Max NEGATIVE Number under 0 NOWHERE does it state that other numbers are not present or function should be limited to negative.  d < Decimal.Zero).Max() looks for numbers under zero and it works only for negative numbers.

Comment: *"You sound frustrated for no reason"*. There's a reason. Several in fact. I'm trying to get you to provide a full and clear explanation for the sake of this question and any you might ask in the future but you seem determined to assume that question is perfect as it is. It's not. If you don't acknowledge that then you're going to ask bad questions in future as well. You're telling me to ignore the question but if everyone who thinks your question is bad ignores it then you'll get no help at all.